# Extend object in Javascript

Tags: javascript, typescript, oop

I want to extend an object by `Object.assign()`:

`extend.js`:

```
module.exports = {
   get csrfOptions() {
        return Object.assign({}, defaultOptions, this.securityOptions.csrf); //can't read property csrf of undefined
    }
}
```

`a.js`:

```
const extend = require('./extend.js');
const obj = {
   securityOptions: {
     csrf: {
       name: 'laoqiren'
     }
   }
}
Object.assign(obj,extend);
```

It comes the error that `can't read property csrf of undefined`, it seems that when calling `Object.assign()`, the `getter` of `csrfOptions` function runs, but `this` doesn't point to `obj` in `a.js`, so the error comes out.

Then, how to extend `obj` in `a.js` using the `extend.js` ?

Comment: That looks like typescript, but you never mention it nor have the tag for it. Also you misspelled `require`.

Comment: I think the module.exports part contains a couple of errors. First of all the white space in the fn name and CSRFOptions?

Comment: Small tip  `extend`  whenever you pass a function , `this` is undefined,.. This is were bind comes in..  IOW:  you could try  `Object.assign(obj, extend.bind(obj)`

Comment: @Keith the object doesn't has the `bind` method

Comment: Oh, yes..Reading it wrong.. how are you calling `csrfOptions` ?

Comment: @Keith When calling `Object.assign()`, it runs automatically.

Comment: Can you provide the desired output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Object.assign` copies property values. You need to "redefine" properties using `Object.defineProperties(obj, Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptors(extend))` instead.

That is why you get an error when trying to get the value of `csrfOptions`.

```js
const defaultOptions = {};

const extend = {
   get csrfOptions() {
        return Object.assign({}, defaultOptions, this.securityOptions.csrf); //can't read property csrf of undefined
    }
}

const obj = {
   securityOptions: {
     csrf: {
       name: 'laoqiren'
     }
   }
}

Object.defineProperties(obj, Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptors(extend))

console.log(obj.csrfOptions);
```